# BsonRegularExpression in Mongodb driver doesn't return desired value

Tags: c#, json, regex, mongodb

Suppose I have database named GSCADB and collection named GSCALogs, and each document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "5d6f514c19038b8b38aec8d7",
    "SHA-256": "839c95cb99e8243d762ccb6f33ed8e1550b6848f739556e71dc8bcf684a159c5",
    "File Name": "Settings.settings",
    "Start Job Date": "2019-09-04T05:53:43.397Z"
}
```

and I want to know how many documents have `Start Job Date` that starts with `2019-09`

For now I have:

```
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("GSCADB");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("GSCALogs");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("Start Job Date", new BsonRegularExpression("^(2019-09)"));
var countedDocuments = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
MessageBox.Show(countedDocuments.Count.ToString());
```

But it prints always `0`, what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try using mongo shell or some client program to tryout the find against mongo first? Also as side note: you can call to .Count(filter) so mongo will count the elements for you instead of retrieving all the documents elevating the structures in memory and the counting

Comment: @PabloRecalde The document exists, I can see it in `MongoDB Compass`

Comment: @PabloRecalde I will take the `.Count(filter) ` advice..

Comment: Yes, but have you tried to query it with a regex filter like you're doing in c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what as the problem, the was saved as datetime and not as string, after writing the date as string to the DB it worked with this code:

```
...
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("Start Job Date", new BsonRegularExpression("^(2019-09)","i"));
var countedDocuments = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
MessageBox.Show(countedDocuments.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mongodb query for getting your output

db.getCollection('GSCALogs').find({ Start Job Date: { $regex: new RegExp('^.*' + "2019-09" + '.*', 'i') } }).count()

- It will return the actual count in which "Start Job Date" is "2019-09"